# Module definition file using premake5

Tags: dll, premake

How to set up module definition file(.def) using premake5?
I tried this:

```lua
buildoptions {"/DEF:\"name.def\""}
```

But that does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

My bad, you need just to include .def file in your project